# matching two pandas dataframe values

Tags: string, pandas, dataframe, match, locate

I have two separate pandas dataframes:

```
 IDr = pd.read_csv(file1,header=None,delim_whitespace=True,usecols=[0])
 print IDr

           0
 0    467770
 1    467080
 2    467060
 3    466950
 4    A0W030
 5    A0C540
 6    D2F230
 ...
```

and

```
      IDg = pd.read_csv(file2,header=None,delim_whitespace=True,usecols=[0,4])

print IDg

      0      4
 0    C1I230    6.5
 1    466940   14.0
 2    466900    0.0
 25   467420    0.5
 26   A0W030 -998.0
 27   A0C540    0.0
 28   D2F230    2.5
 ...
```

The task is to match when a value in IDr matches an id in IDg, and to extract the second column number (pandas index number) within IDg.

There might be some instances where there is no match (in which, a '0' is fine), but there will never be more than 1 match (there is only one number/letter combination in each file).

For the example provided, the match above would be

```
'-998.0' for 'A0W030', 

'0.0' for A0C540, and 

'2.5' for D2F230 

0 for 467770, 467080, 467060, and 466950.
```

I have tried the locate, str.contains, and str.match functions, and nothing seems to be working. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use merge

```
df1.merge(df2, how = 'left').fillna(0)

    0   4
0   467770  0.0
1   467080  0.0
2   467060  0.0
3   466950  0.0
4   A0W030  -998.0
5   A0C540  0.0
6   D2F230  2.5
```

Or map and assign the column to df1

```
df1['new'] = df1['0'].map(df2.set_index('0')['4']).fillna(0)


    0       new
0   467770  0.0
1   467080  0.0
2   467060  0.0
3   466950  0.0
4   A0W030  -998.0
5   A0C540  0.0
6   D2F230  2.5
```